# Posting to friends wall with dialog feed? (fb feb 6th '13 changes)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

I'm using PHP SDK to create a post to a friends wall, before the feb 6th changes, I just used the graph api and /[friend id]/feed/ with post and parameters. I'm not sure exactly how to use the dialog feed to create a post to another wall. This is how i have it set up and link them to the url. This is the page it leads me to:

"The page you requested was not found.
You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive."

```
$url = "https://www.facebook.com/[friend id]/feed?
 app_id=[app id]&
 redirect_uri=[redirect url]&
 link=[link]&
 message=[message]&
 picture=[picture url]&
 caption=[caption]&
 description=[description]&
 name=[name]";
```

//just using facebook.com/dialog/feed?... works fine for posting to my own wall tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use the `to` parameter when invoking the feed dialog via direct url. Check the "Direct URL Example" and "Properties" block of [the feed dialog reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

The final url would look something like this (notice the `/dialog/feed` and `to=...` parts):

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
        app_id=[appid]&
        link=[link]&
        picture=[picture url]&
        name=[name]&
        caption=[caption]&
        description=[description]&
        redirect_uri=[redirect uri]&
        to=[friend id]';
```

Comment: @complex587: For some reason that works if i just fill in the data (appid, link..) and go to the url, goes to a dialog box, returns me post id after redirect_uri. But for it wont do that through code, i have it set up as: header('Location:' . $url); which just goes to the redirect_uri without posting (or adding the post id.

Comment: Yes, this endpoint is designed to be used with a browser by your app's users. The breaking change is that you can no longer post to your users friend's wall purely through graph API. You will have to involve them into this from now on. (using this endpoint probably more convenient with the js sdk's `FB.ui()` which embeds the same dialog.

Comment: Is there a way to do what FB.ui() does with the php sdk? because if I just go to the $url via the address bar it works, but the same $url just redirects back to my localhost without posting if i do it via header('Location:' . $url);

Comment: No documented way i know of. As far as i can tell, the reason of this change was to prevent posting in the name of the users without them approving it explicitly.

Comment: Any idea for the header just redirecting back to localhost instead of do what the url points to?

Comment: nvm, figured it out. Edited OP

Comment: Whoops, sorry i edited the wrong post, cant change it back. Thanks for the help btw, it seems to be working as intended.